# How can I summarize an object the same way Format-List does?

Tags: powershell, formatting

For example, looking at a processes threads shows something like this:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Process)[0] | Format-List -Property Threads

Threads : {1548, 1600, 15940, 13996}
```

But if you actually grab that property directly, it looks like this:

```
PS C:\> (Get-Process)[0].Threads

BasePriority            : 8
CurrentPriority         : 9
Id                      : 1548
IdealProcessor          : 
PriorityBoostEnabled    : 
PriorityLevel           : 
PrivilegedProcessorTime : 
StartAddress            : 8790537024736
StartTime               : 
ThreadState             : Wait
TotalProcessorTime      : 
UserProcessorTime       : 
WaitReason              : UserRequest
ProcessorAffinity       : 
Site                    : 
Container               : 

BasePriority            : 8
... etc
```

Format list obviously has a method to summarize objects intelligently. It took a list of objects, pulled out a representative property from each one, and displayed it as a short array. I cannot find a method or cmdlet that allows me to summarize an collection of objects in the same manner.

I want to be able to pass an arbitrary collection of objects to a method and have it summarize. This is used when listing email addresses in Exchange objects, listing groups in AD objects, and many other places... I doubt these are all special cases.

---

To expand (after learning more from @JoelSmith's comments):

.NET Objects have [formatting definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg580992(v=vs.85).aspx) that are used by Powershell when [formatting output](https://superuser.com/questions/469980/how-does-formatting-works-with-a-powershell-function-that-returns-a-set-of-eleme). Additional details are available using `help about_Format.ps1xml`[[1]](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847831.aspx). These definitions are generic and can be accessed by any command, but by default there are no functions in Powershell to directly retrieve the output of an object property directly as it would be displayed in Format-List.

One hackish workaround is to split and strip the output like so:

```
(Get-Mailbox user | Format-List -Property Languages | Out-String).Split(':')[1].Trim()
    # => {en-US,fr-CA}
```

However this method is extremely fragile, and will fail when the output spans multiple lines or contains a colon in the output:

```
(Get-Mailbox user | Format-List -Property EmailAddresses | Out-String).Split(':')[1].Trim()
    # => {smtp
```

What is needed is a method that reads the formatting definition defined for the object and retrieves it directly, then use it to output the desired string. I have failed to find any example online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the

```
PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayProperty
```

and

```
PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet
```

properties of your objects to determine the default properties that should be displayed for each type. You can read more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/02/18/psstandardmembers-the-stealth-property.aspx). We've run into a similar problem recently in our like PowerShell project. You can find [this discussion we've had helpful](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/108). There are some subtle differences between PS v2 and v3 which we debate on that thread.

Comment: That is excellent, and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Adam, I really appreciate your taking the time to look at this old question.

Answer (score 1):

Usually .ToString() works but sometimes they forget to implement that method.

```
 (Get-Process)[0] | %{$_.Threads.Id}
```

EDIT: to answer your comment below

```
(Get-Process)[0] | Format-List -Property Threads | Out-String
```

Unfortunately not all cmdlets are the same.

Comment: What's strange is normally you can pipe to get-member to see what the underlying properties, methods, type of object, etc of the cmdlet.


when I do it with your cmdlet here I get multiple different types



(Get-Process)[0] | Format-List -Property Threads | get-member


TypeName:Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
TypeName:Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
TypeName:Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData

Comment: That would work for this specific case only... I cannot imagine that Format-List has 500 methods to handle all the different types of collections used in the various cmdlets. I specifically need to be able to pass an **arbitrary** collection; Threads is just an example.

Comment: a cmdlet can specify what the default table view and list view shows and it can be custom, while a lot of cmdlets help you with the .ToString() method not every cmdlet implements it, not much you can do besides reformat what format-list spits out. Like this:(Get-Process)[0] | Format-List -Property Threads | Out-String

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your terminology; Threads is not a cmdlet, it is a collection of objects. It has no code associated with it directly. The Format-List cmdlet is somehow capable of reformatting a wide variety of collections of objects. Is this functionality externally available? Your workaround has a lot of extra unrelated text.

Comment: Format-List is a way to format the Get-Process cmdlet. All cmdlets are objects. What you are asking for is why the person who wrote Get-Process made the output they did using Format-List. This was configured by the creator in an xml file associated with the cmdlet. For more info on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878278(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Get-Process is a cmdlet, but Threads is not. I am not sure you are understanding the difference between a command and the data it returns.

Comment: Threads is a property of a cmdlet I'm not confusing anything read the article above.

Comment: Did some searching and you can customize what Format-List shows http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849884.aspx

Comment: there is also Format-Custom

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
(Get-Process)[0].Threads | Format-Table -Property ID -AutoSize

   Id
   --
13060
13064
13068
13072
13076
13080
13084
```

This needs to be customized for each cmdlet depending on what the output is and what fields you need. The reason it doesn't work with just `(Get-Process)[0] | Format-Table -Property Threads -AutoSize` is because `Threads` returns thread-objects, and an array of objects are displayed like your first sample (string-presentation of your objects in a collection `{ .. }`) .

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I can tell so far:

The Id property is the default display property for a thread object (System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread). 
I couldn't find any tracks of this in any of PowerShell's type files but I can change the way Format-* display threads (requires PowerShell 3.0).

By default the format cmdlets prints the Id value of each thread object:

```
Threads : {1548, 1600, 15940, 13996}
```

Formatting cmdlets checks the value of the `$FormatEnumerationLimit` variable (default is 4) to decide how to format the object. 
If the result is one object (scalar) only it will print as:

```
Threads : 1548
```

If it's a collection of items and the collection count is up to the value of `$FormatEnumerationLimit` (4) it will display as:

```
Threads : {1548, 1600, 15940, 13996}
```

A count greater than `$FormatEnumerationLimit` will look like (... indicates that there are more objects):

```
Threads : {1548, 1600, 15940, 13996...}
```

I can tell Id is the default property in use because I can change it to another property and see its value reflecting in the output.
For example, Here I'm setting the ThreadState as the default display property:

```
PS> Update-TypeData -TypeName System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread -DefaultDisplayProperty ThreadState -Force
PS> (Get-Process)[0] | Format-List -Property Threads

Threads : {Wait, Wait, Wait, Wait...}

# revert back    
PS> Update-TypeData -TypeName System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread -DefaultDisplayProperty Id -Force
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Definitely useful, but the goal is to have a way to retrieve that text after the colon directly, without text hacks and `Format-List`. Most of the objects I would like to manipulate already have good formatting information... but there is no function that reads that metadata except the `Format-*` cmdlets.

Comment: I must have read your question differently. If the goal is to get the Thread of each objects, refer to the property directly, or expand it using select-object.

Comment: He's basically asking for magical properties that don't exist. Sad to say powershell isn't that smart Myriddin. You need to quit being lazy and code individually for each type you need.

Comment: format-list obviously took its information from .thread.id how much more time does it take to write (Get-Process)[0].threads.id for each of the types you want? Like 2 seconds.

Comment: How many times must you ignore the portion of the comment that says Threads is just one of many examples. I need a function that reads the formatting metadata stored in the format documents and can print many different objects in a clear and succinct way. Threads is not even one of them! It's just an easy example that everyone has access to (I'm actually more intereted in AD, Exchange, and O365 objects). I do not want to write 50 special cases when the work has already been done... but I do not know how to use that metadata to do the output formatting that Format-List does.